# soft keyboard shows on Nexus 7 but not on Nexus 6P

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I am creating a simple tip calculator program from a book and am having trouble getting the numeric soft keyboard to show up when running the app on a Nexus 6P.  If I run the app on a Nexus 7 it works as expected.  Is there a possible problem with the Nexus 6P or is there something I have overlooked?

I have tried several settings in the Manifest for the Activity:
    android:windowSoftInputMode = "stateAlwaysVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"

Started out with stateAlwaysVisible and added the others to try to solve the problem.

I have the requestFocus and the input type in the xml:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/amountEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="6">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>/>


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/amountDisplayTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:padding="@dimen/textview_padding"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

In the java code, I again try to set the focus on the amountEditText field:

```
amountEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountEditText);
    amountEditText.requestFocus();
    amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(amountEditTextWatcher);
    amountEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resetUI();
        }
    });
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(amountEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

When I run this on the Nexus 7 (android 5.1.1) the soft keyboard is displayed when the application is started, as expected.

When I run this on the Nexus 6P (android 6.0.1) the soft keyboard is not displayed when the application is started.  However if I tap the input field several times, the soft keyboard may decide to be displayed.  If it is, it is a smaller keyboard then with the Nexus 7.

I have generated the code for these devices in Android Studio 1.5 and 2.0 Beta 4.  Same results.

Targeted SDK version is 23, with minimum SDK version of 21.  Tried changing the targeted SDK version to 22 - no joy.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Edit**

After further testing, it looks like GridLayout was having problems with constraints and removing stuff, although the error messages are not very clear on what the problem was:

D/android.widget.GridLayout: horizontal constraints: x2-x1>=482, x2-x0<=2112, x2-x1<=100 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x2-x0<=2112, x2-x1<=100.

D/android.widget.GridLayout: vertical constraints: y2-y1>=113, y3-y2>=0, y4-y3>=113, y5-y4>=169, y6-y5>=169, y7-y6>=0, y8-y7>=0, y2-y1<=91, y1-y0<=186 are inconsistent; permanently removing: y2-y1<=91.

Again, this only appears to be a problem when I am on the Nexus 6P.

So, I re-wrote the application xml to use RelativeLayout with embedded LinearLayouts instead of the GridLayout.

App works better now, but the soft keyboard does not automatically appear until I tap the EditText field.

I still requestFocus in onCreate and use the:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode = "stateAlwaysVisible|adjustResize"
```

for the activity in the manifest.

Since the application works well enough for my use, which all it was intended for, I think I have gone as far as I am willing to at this point on this application and can consider this issue closed in this case.

However, if anyone comes up with something else I could try, I am willing to give it a go.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. The keyboard would show once and never again, only on Nexus 6P and landscape orientation. To fix I changed the `showSoftInput` call to this when on landscape: `imm.showSoftInput(myEditText, 0);`

Comment: Tried the imm.showSoftInput(myEditText, 0);  No help.  As the application stands now, when the app first displays, there is no keyboard.  If I tap the amount field, the keyboard appears and stays there, unless I press the back button or switch to landscape.  Will probably leave the app like it is for now.  Thanks for the suggestion.